# Microsoft Speech API (SAPI) UserTraining syntax

Tags: sapi

I've got a working autohotkey script which brings up the Windows Speech Recognition Training interface with custom text for input.
If you've ever done the training for Windows Speech Recognition, you know it has you say a short line of text, then once it recognizes that line, goes to a new screen with another short line of text.

I can't figure out how to "break" my two-sentence text into two separate training screens so the user won't have to read thousands of lines of training text all in the same breath with no mistakes.

If anyone figures this out I'll love you forever

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
hwnd:=WinExist("A")
Title:="My App's Training"
RC := ComObjCreate("SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext")
MyTrainingText := new TrainingText("Some custom text", Title)
MyTrainingText.get_MyMethod()
MyTrainingText := new TrainingText("Some more training text", Title)
MyTrainingText.get_MyMethod()


Class TrainingText 
{
    __New(x, y)
    {
        this.Text := x
        this.Title := y
    }

    get_MyMethod()
    {
        Title := this.Title
        trainingText := this.Text
        if RC.Recognizer.IsUISupported("UserTraining")
        {
        RC.Recognizer.DisplayUI(ComObj(3,hwnd), Title, "UserTraining", traningText)
        }
        else MsgBox, Not supported
    }
}
```

Comment: does not seem to work, the else msgbox, not supported gets fired and nothing else happens (corrected typo traningText to trainingText and still doesn't work)

Comment: I wrote that up fast, note the untested. I'm new to using Class's in AHK and I may have fouled something up. I'll post a revision in a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

The user training text needs to be a [double-null terminated string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx), also known as a multistring.   Each null-terminated substring will be a separate utterance.  I'm not familiar enough with AutoHotKey to know how to build one in that language.

In C#, a function to convert a string array to a multistring would look something like this:

```
static string StringArrayToMultiString(params string[] values)
{
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    StringBuilder multiString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string s in values)
    {
        multiString.Append(s);
        multiString.Append('\0');
    }
    return multiString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you for the hint eric, can you build one in any language? i can translate it to ahk

Comment: Added one in C#.   Hope it's helpful.